# YAML Syntax Error: Incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed at

Tags: api, swagger, specifications, swagger-editor

I'm writing swagger spec in YAML and getting vague errors. I've mapped my paths and definitions I think correctly, and not sure what this error means:

> YAML Syntax Error Incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is
>   missed at line 66, column 30: format: int64schema: ^t

Lines:

```
 Line 65:         type: integer
 Line 66:         format: int64
```

Swagger:

```
  /product/{productId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - content
      summary: Find product item by ID
      description: Returns a product item when ID < 10.  ID > 10 or nonintegers will simulate API error conditions
      operationId: getProductItemByID
      produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: productId
          description: ID of menu item that needs to be fetched
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Product"
      responses:
        "404":
          description: Product item not found
        "200":
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Product"
        "400":
          description: Invalid ID supplied
      security:
        - api_key: []
        - my_auth:
          - write
          - read
```

Then at bottom of swagger file in definitions:

```
definitions:

  Product:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      category:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Category'
      name:
        type: string
      detail:
        type: string
```

Comment: These your 2 present sections of YAML parse *without* this or any error by just pasting verbatim in order into leading parser http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml -at least when I did it now
• ...just after paste then insert a 1st line of say ‘first section:’ so now both sections have same indent level
• Did u know this wd happen?
• Why then did u get this error before? -since YAML spec has since updated to not have this error?

Comment: For anyone coming here that doesn't use a YAML formatter, and is writing this blind... there's a good chance your indentation or syntax is wrong. You'll want to find yourself a nice yaml extension formatter (like VSCode plugin recommends), and/or resolve that formatting issue.

Answer (score 4):

From [swagger 2.0 spec](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject), if 'in' parameter is a "path" you can't use a schema.
I think there is a mistake and you should use :

```
/product/{productId}:
  get:
    tags:
      - content
    summary: Find product item by ID
    description: Returns a product item when ID < 10.  ID > 10 or nonintegers will simulate API error conditions
    operationId: getProductItemByID
    produces:
      - application/json
      - application/xml
    parameters:
      - in: path
        name: productId
        description: ID of menu item that needs to be fetched
        required: true
        type: integer
        format: int64
    responses:
      "404":
        description: Product item not found
      "200":
        description: successful operation
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Product"
      "400":
        description: Invalid ID supplied
...
```